# create cards in a specific order using bootstrap or CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I am creating a website for blog. I want to arrange cards in this order:
[image]

But I am unable to do it using bootstrap. Here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"> <Card>
        <img className="card-img-top" src='{activity.image[0].url}' alt=""/>
     
      {/* <Link to={`/product/${product.name}`}>  */}
          <Card.Body>
              {/* <Link to={`/product/${activity.id}`}>  */}
              <Card.Title>Title</Card.Title>
              {/* </Link> */}
             
              <Card.Text>$Price</Card.Text> 
              <Button className='btn-gallery'>See Blog</Button>
          </Card.Body>
          
  </Card>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">.col-md-4 .offset-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 offset-md-3">.col-md-3 .offset-md-3</div>
<div class="col-md-3 offset-md-3">.col-md-3 .offset-md-3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">.col-md-6 .offset-md-3</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me in creating cards just like the way it is shown in this screenshot?

Comment: Show what you tried

Comment: I have added the code in my question.

Comment: I have just added the code for creating columns and rows, but It is not arranging the cards as I need it

Comment: Use a nested card grid, i.e., use one `row` for the outer 3 `col` and put another `row` inside the middle `col`: https://www.codeply.com/p/MBbUzjXIxd

Comment: You may also want to look into a Masonry plugin or extension for Bootstrap, or explore flexbox (use columns so that it adds content top-to-bottom, then left-to-right).

Comment: You can use Bootstrap and Masonry. official example here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/masonry/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope below code will get you a solution for what you're looking,
In this i've used row-col structure and cards of bootstrap.

As you can see i have taken 1 parent row in which 3 columns are wrapped up and among those three cols i gave 100% height and for the middle one i've used another row to wrap the 2 columns.

For the responsive row-cols-md-4 (for larger devices) and row-cols-1 (for smaller devices) used.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/ogxaecu2/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="card-section">
    <div class="container p-3 bg-secondary">
      <div class="row row-cols-md-4 row-cols-1 g-5 justify-content-center">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-body text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-column">
              <img width="100%" height="auto" src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/80/3888/2592.jpg?hmac=zD95NwXZ7mGAMj-z4444Elf43I4HJvd7Afm2tloweLw" alt="Image">
              <h2>Some text</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col h-100">
          <div class="row row-cols-1 g-5">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-column">
                  <img width="100%" height="auto" src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/9/5000/3269.jpg?hmac=cZKbaLeduq7rNB8X-bigYO8bvPIWtT-mh8GRXtU3vPc" alt="Image">
                  <h2>Some text</h2>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-column">
                  <img width="100%" height="auto" src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/13/2500/1667.jpg?hmac=SoX9UoHhN8HyklRA4A3vcCWJMVtiBXUg0W4ljWTor7s" alt="Image">
                  <h2>Some text</h2>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-body text-center d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-column">
              <img width="100%" height="auto" src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/20/3670/2462.jpg?hmac=CmQ0ln-k5ZqkdtLvVO23LjVAEabZQx2wOaT4pyeG10I" alt="Image">
              <h2>Some text</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```